What's going on with my wrong/absent port mapping for my container in my EC2 instance?
Preview: Before you crucify me: yes, there are many similar posts. I have went through the majority of them (including many video tutorials) but none seem to match exactly my setup. And yes, I know this is a long one. Trust me, I wish it wasn't. Thank you in advance for the help.
My Goal: Create EC2 instance and connect to the container within over the internet.
Minimum Reproducible Example:

Create .NET Blazor App
Build DockerFile from within Visual Studio    (Right-click on your project name in Solution     Explorer -> Add ->    Docker
Support (you might    have to change directory structure for    the
added projects in the    Dockerfile as they can get messed up
doing it this way).
Create image locally
Tag image locally
Push to DockerHub
Fast forwarding… Create Task Definition with container mapping to port 8080 (if you're using AWS Console, which I did.)
Obviously update your security groups to allow any IP to map to the container's    port 8080 (you can see how my Security Group
(default) looks below.

My Chronological (Condensed) Steps (Broken down into subsections for better readability):
Local Environment (probably not needed but I realize some people such as myself need context):

Created a SQL Server database, Blazor App, .NET Web API. Everything works locally.
Created Dockerfile for Blazor App (In Visual Studio -> Right-Click on Project -> Add -> Docker Support).
Created Dockerfile for .NET Web API.
Created Docker compose yml file.
Ran containers. Local containerized environment works seamlessly.
Working towards AWS now…
Tagged and pushed local images to DockerHub repositories (ECR alternative)

AWS Environment:

Created task definition through AWS Console for the Blazor App, Web API, and SQL Server Images.
Found myself in over my head so turned big task into small task.
Working with only Blazor App now…
Created Cluster.
Created Service.
Instance is running in Cluster.
At this point, I'm unable to access the app through the Amazon-provided Public DNS or the Public IPv4:Port combo.

NOTE: From here, I will be referring to two different Blazor Apps:

"Blazor_custom_app," the app with all my business logic. The one I
originally created a docker image and task definition for.
"Blazor_generic_app," the app to test if the code within my Blazor_custom_app was     causing the same networking problems. If
the Blazor_generic_app ran into the same     networking problem, this
would rule out any self-imposed problems coming from my own     code
modifications within the Blazor_custom_app.The Blazor_generic_app,
as the name suggests, had no code modifications.

Debugging: Part 1

Pinged IP - EC2 instance with Blazor_custom_app is running and
reachable.
Checked firewall settings. Tried to access the app on both Windows and Mac - could not. Firewall settings looked clean on both  Mac and
Windows.
SSH'ed to EC2 Instance running container for Blazor_custom_app
Ran "docker ps"
The container is running
Ran sudo netstat -tuln
Container running Blazor_custom_app was mapped to 127.0.0.1 (I forget the command that showed this, but it led me to this post.
Went back to Program.cs file inside of Blazor_custom_app and added the following:


    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_EC2") == "true") 
    {
      builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:8080");        
    }



Reran the app locally and through containerized environment through Docker Desktop.
Everything worked fine as the environment
variable (AWS_EC2 in the code above) was set to "false."
Created new Task Definition, Cluster, and Service for Blazor_custom_app.
Included Environment variable AWS_EC2 for the container running the image for Blazor_custom_app.
Still could not access app (I guess my explicit port mapping in my Program.cs didn't work).
Throughout the aforementioned steps, I rechecked Security Groups, Route Table, Network ACL, and my Task Definition atleast 30
times. Screenshots, including my Task Definition in JSON, are  below.

Task Definition:
{
    "family": "blazo_demo_app",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "blazor_demo_app_container",
            "image": "thecodeiackiller/blazor_demo:latest",
            "cpu": 205,
            "memory": 307,
            "memoryReservation": 205,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "blazor_demo_app_container-8080-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/blazo_demo_app",
                    "mode": "non-blocking",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "max-buffer-size": "25m",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx2345:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx2345:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "volumes": [],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "512",
    "memory": "1024",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}

Security Group (default):

Route Table:

Network ACL:

Debugging: Part 2

Created Blazor_generic_app. Did all in-between steps leading up to
the creation of the EC2 instance.
SSH'ed to EC2 Instance running
container for Blazor_custom_app
Ran "docker ps"
The container is running - but has no associated port:



Again, no ports upon further container inspection:



Stopped and removed the container running Blazor_generic_app within the EC2 instance
Explicitly remapped the container ports with the following command:

docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name blazor_demo_container <username>/blazor_demo


Using my Auto generated IP in AWS Console (3.95.178.4) with port 8080,  I can now access the "Blazor_demo_app."
I realize this only puts a band-aid (if you can even call it that) on the root problem, but this does rule out a myriad of potential problems including Firewall issues.

My Conclusion: The problem is one of two things: a default .NET issue or an issue with how I'm creating my docker image. The problem isn't with my custom app specifically as both the generic Blazor app and custom Blazor App ran into the same problem. I feel like my Docker image is the culprit, but can't pinpoint the exact issue.
Dockerfile:
# Base image for running the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

# Build stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src

# Corrected paths for the project files
COPY ["blazor_demo.csproj", "./"]

# Restore dependencies
RUN dotnet restore "./blazor_demo.csproj"

# Copy all files and build
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src"
RUN dotnet build "blazor_demo.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# Publish stage
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "blazor_demo.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Final image
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "blazor_demo.dll"]

Moving forward: I read that either an Application Load Balancer or Elastic Load Balancer might be my best bet as this allows me to not have to worry about my port mappings. If true, that's fine, but I'd still like to get to the root cause of this problem.

A few questions, if the goal is to connect to the container over the internet why do you want an EC2? That means you'll have a full machine for hosting a container. You're better off using the ECS service and spinning up your container there. Alternatively EKS or Fargate, but for a simple container the Elastic Container Service is a better choice than an EC2.

Thank you for the comment. When you say "full machine," I think you're wrong. Apart of the process of spinning up and EC2 instance is provisioning the vCPU and Memory that will be used so that the right amount is allocated to your containers within you're task. EC2, like EKS, gives you more control over you're clusters in large scale settings, which is something I want to get used to. Again, and could be wrong, but I don't think my choice of EC2 over Fargate or EKS is causing the port mapping problem.

A full Virtual Machine as opposed to paying for a container. I used to teach AWS at a top Bank & I'm pretty sure I am right. Imagine this scenario a Lambda executing a small function once a day, its $0 per month. If I had that same Lambda in an EC2 I'd have to pay minimum $5 per month. Under the hood AWS Lambda is actually an EKS cluster with short lived (usually small) containers. If I put my Lambda on an EKS that will cost $200 per month. I'm right and so are you. If you want to configure K8 all yourself (good on ya) use https://www.hetzner.com/ a fraction of AWS costs with full control.

Changed my network mode from "awsvpc" to "default," which allowed me to map the host and container ports exactly how they were defined on Docker Desktop. "Default" in AWS Task Definition is equivalent to "bridge" within Docker compose. From what I understand, changing this allows the containers in AWS to have the same configuration as the container environment that was created when everything was initially spun up locally.
